# How to retrieve images from a web directory?

Tags: android

Is there by any chance a way to retrieve all the images on a web server/directory and view them on a grid like gallery or a simple gallery view on android? I do not want to list all the web address of the images and then view them on my app gallery because that way i cannot update the gallery i.e. newly added images won't be displayed since the source code of my app cannot be modified while it is installed on a device (that was an insane idea lol) .could anyone help? thank you anyways

Comment: could you add a webservice, so you can receive a json file containing all images?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand well what you want to do but i developed a project similar what you want to do.

- First develop a web api which returns last modified date time of your web application. (where you hold your pictures Api is not necessary you can save it into a file in your server if you wish)
- Second when user runs application check this last modified date time and if web app's last modified date time is newer than your last sync date time, sync your pictures folder in your mobile application and show them to user in a grid or something else.
- When user made a change in your mobile application apply changes to your web application, update your sync date time and last modified date time.